# Blitting text in pygame

Tags: python, string, text, pygame, blit

Im making a game to practice mygame and im creating a highscore screen but i cant seem to properly blit the text how i want

here is the highscore method

```
def high_screen(self):
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("impact", 20)
    scorefile = open('highscores.txt', 'r')
    highscores = scorefile.read()
    label = myfont.render((highscores), 1, (0,0,0))
    screen.blit(label, (0, 0))

    self.back = pygame.image.load('resources/screen/back.png')
    self.back_r = self.back.get_bounding_rect()
    self.back_r.x,self.back_r.y = (100,600)
    screen.blit(self.back,(100, 600))
    screen.blit(self.player,(self.mouse_pos))
    if self.player_r.colliderect(self.back_r)and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        self.state = 1
```

this ggets the highscores from a .txt file and blits them but it blits them on one line when i want each score blitted about 100 pixels down from the one above it

so how can i make it so that it splits the text from the file and blits each score 100 pixels down?

Thank You

-Christian Careaga

Answer (score 0):

You could make a file for each score and then simply do something like:

```
screen.blit(label1, (0, 0))
screen.blit(labe2, (0, 100))
screen.blit(labe3, (0, 100))
#etc
```

Comment: thats true but i think i want like 10 scores but i dont want to have 10 files

Comment: Well im not great at python data storage, I think you could use shelve, and instead of 10 files just have 10 keys.

Answer (score 0):

if your score is in a file which suppose looks like this:

---

score1 - 10

score2 - 23

score3 - 34

---

then you can use this to separate the scores into different texts

```
scorelist = [text.split('\n') for text in open('score.txt','r')]
##when you read the file from python you will get this string : score1 - 10\nscore2 - 23\nscore3 - 34
```

then to bit this onto a surface, use this code:

```
for i in enumerate(scorelist,1):
    surface.blit(i[1],(100,100+i[0]*100))
```