# Pygame Issue during font displaying

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem when I try to display my font ( when the hero is dead ) but nothing is displayed. Please help me to find where the issue originates.

```
if hero.life == 0 or hero.life < 0:
    hero.image =  pygame.image.load("images/grave2.png").convert_alpha()
    text_end = font_end.render("GAME OVER",1,(255,255,255))
    fenetre.blit(fond_jeu, (0,0))
    fenetre.blit(text_end, (30, 30))
    hero.alive = 0
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393544/writing-text-in-pygame#23393753

Comment: thx i will have a look at it

Comment: Please read the [minimal, complete and verfiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page. If you don't provide an mcve, it's difficult or even impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where font_end instanciation? By some thing like

```py
texte = "Mon texte à afficher"
font_end = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold",22,bold=False,italic=False)
text = font_end.render(texte, True)
```

And for blit :

```py
mySurface.blit(text,(x, y))
pygame.display.update()
```